# Ember acceptance tests for build artifacts

Tags: ember.js, acceptance-testing, ember-testing

Is there a standard way to acceptance test build artifacts in Ember? One specific use case is an addon that runs `addAddonToProject` or `addBowerPackageToProject`, then asserting whether the `bower.json` or `package.json` looks the way you expect.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/tomdale/ember-cli-addon-tests seems to be the best way to test addon artifacts.

More specifically, https://github.com/tildeio/ember-cli-fastboot/blob/master/tests/acceptance/package-json-test.js#L35-L41 to see reading a `package.json` and asserting.